# Retrieve all songs from the iPod library without useing MPMediaPickerController

Tags: c#, ios, mpmediaquery

I'm writing an iPhone app to retrieve all songs from a users iPod library on their iPhone, but I don't want to use the `MPMediaPickerController`. Meanwhile, I will display the songs in a custom ListView/TableView.

I've written a query to select all songs from the users iPhone:

```
MPMediaQuery mq = new MPMediaQuery ();
var value = NSNumber.FromInt32 ((int) MPMediaType.Music); 
var type = MPMediaItemProperty.MediaType; 
var predicate = MPMediaPropertyPredicate.PredicateWithValue (value, type);
mq.AddFilterPredicate (predicate);
```

How do I run this against the iPhones iPod library without having to use the MPMediaPickerController?

Comment: (Converted to answer.)

Comment: simpler version of value setting: var value = NSObject.FromObject (MPMediaType.Music)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Items` property of the `MPMediaQuery mq` will contain the results that you'd use to populate your view.